# Safari on mobile resets CSRF token in Flask GAE session

Tags: google-app-engine, session, safari, csrf, flask-wtforms

I'm running Flask on Google App Engine via the [Flask GAE Template](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template).

I've implemented the CSRF protection outlined in the [Flask-WTF docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html) and I've tested that it works.

I've run into an interesting problem where the `csrf_token` session variable gets reset by my iPhone's browser (Safari). I'll describe what led me to this conclusion, but first, here is my code:

Relevant code in views.py:

```
def test_page(code):
    form = forms.TestCSRFForm()
    return render_template('csrf_test.html', form=form)

def test_ajax():
    form = forms.TestCSRFForm()
    return "{}".format(form.validate_on_submit())
```

Relevant code in urls.py:

```
app.add_url_rule('/csrftest/<code>', 'test_page', view_func=views.test_page, methods=['GET'])

app.add_url_rule('/csrftest/', 'test_ajax', view_func=views.test_ajax, methods=['POST'])
```

My template (csrf_test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function go() {

            var csrftoken = $('{{ form.csrf_token }}').attr('value');


            alert(csrftoken);

            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type)) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
                    }
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/csrftest/",
                data: { csrf_token: csrftoken }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert(msg);
            });
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="go();">go</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Some logging I've done in Flask-WTF's csrf.py:

```
def generate_csrf(secret_key=None, time_limit=None):
    """Generate csrf token code.

    :param secret_key: A secret key for mixing in the token,
                       default is Flask.secret_key.
    :param time_limit: Token valid in the time limit,
                       default is 3600s.
    """
    if not secret_key:
        secret_key = current_app.config.get(
            'WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY', current_app.secret_key
        )

    if not secret_key:
        raise Exception('Must provide secret_key to use csrf.')

    if time_limit is None:
        time_limit = current_app.config.get('WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT', 3600)

    if 'csrf_token' not in session:
        session['csrf_token'] = hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(64)).hexdigest()

    if time_limit:
        expires = time.time() + time_limit
        csrf_build = '%s%s' % (session['csrf_token'], expires)
    else:
        expires = ''
        csrf_build = session['csrf_token']

    hmac_csrf = hmac.new(
        to_bytes(secret_key),
        to_bytes(csrf_build),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha1
    ).hexdigest()

    logging.info("session['csrf_token'] = %s" % session['csrf_token']) #logging here

    return '%s##%s' % (expires, hmac_csrf)



def validate_csrf(data, secret_key=None, time_limit=None):
    """Check if the given data is a valid csrf token.

    :param data: The csrf token value to be checked.
    :param secret_key: A secret key for mixing in the token,
                       default is Flask.secret_key.
    :param time_limit: Check if the csrf token is expired.
                       default is True.
    """
    if not data or '##' not in data:
        return False

    expires, hmac_csrf = data.split('##', 1)

    if time_limit is None:
        time_limit = current_app.config.get('WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT', 3600)

    if time_limit:
        try:
            expires = float(expires)
        except:
            return False

        now = time.time()
        if now > expires:
            return False

    if not secret_key:
        secret_key = current_app.config.get(
            'WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY', current_app.secret_key
        )

    if 'csrf_token' not in session:
        return False

    logging.info("session['csrf_token'] = %s" % session['csrf_token']) #logging here

    csrf_build = '%s%s' % (session['csrf_token'], expires)
    hmac_compare = hmac.new(
        to_bytes(secret_key),
        to_bytes(csrf_build),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha1
    ).hexdigest()

    logging.info("comparing hmacs: {0} {1}".format(hmac_compare, hmac_csrf)) #logging here
    return safe_str_cmp(hmac_compare, hmac_csrf)
```

Let's say I store the following links in my Notes app on my Phone:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/csrftest/123
http://myapp.appspot.com/csrftest/456
```

If I visit the first link from my phone, and press 'Go', everything works fine:
[image]

The csrf_token session variables are the same when the form is created, and when it's verified, the hmacs are the same as well, and the form is validated.

However, if I double-tap the home button, swipe up on the Safari app (suspend it), and go back to my notes app, then press on the second link (csrftest/456), Safari screws up; it navigates to /csrftest/456 first, and then (I guess, as its hiding the view from the first tab, and opens the second), it **sends another request to /csrftest/123**

You can see this here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, as you can see, the weird second request that Safari sends (to /csrftest/123) resets the csrf_token session variable to something different, and because the hmac for the /csrftest/456 link was generated from **the original** csrf_token session variable, and the hmac is validated with **the new** csrf_token session variable, the hmacs don't match.

Since I can't change Safari's behavior, what can I do to solve this on my end?

Thanks so much. And of course, Happy Thanksgiving :).

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this error? I think I'm hitting something similar :/